# AppDelegate doesn't init viewController right

Tags: iphone, ios, appdelegate

I am using [PaperFoldMenuController](https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFoldMenuController) to create a cool SlideMenu in my App.

In the AppDelegate I define the viewControllers and add them to the SlideMenu Array:

```
// Init viewControllers
       RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
     LivetickerViewController *livetickerViewController = [[LivetickerViewController alloc] init];


// Add view controllers to array
    [viewControllers addObject:rootNavController];
    [viewControllers addObject:livetickerNavController];


    // Add to PaperFoldView
    [_menuController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

I use a storyboard for designing most parts of the LivetickerViewController. But all changes are not shown. I checked that Storyboard is connected with the view.

What is the problem in the code ?

Comment: I'm relatively certain that the Storyboard doesn't actually read your code (other than looking for exported methods and variables). You have to build everything that you want to control with the storyboard within the storyboard. (if it did update with your code, it would need to execute it to allow all possibilities, and that will give quite weird results if you switch to it with incomplete code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've designed your LivetickerViewController in the storyboard, then you need to get it from the storyboard not with alloc init.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
LivetickerViewController *livetickerViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"livetickerViewController"];
```

Make sure that the name of the storyboard is what is actually in your project, and that you have given the view controller an identifier that matches what you pass in the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method.

If you made rootViewController in the storyboard, you should do the same thing with it.